# Navigation Header not hiding in react native

Tags: react-native, header, react-navigation

We are showing navigation side drawer in our react native application.
So, In that, For particular screen, We have to disable gestures.
And for complete app, We are hiding navigation header too.

```
MyStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = 'unlocked';
  if ((navigation.state.index === 2) || (navigation.state.index === 3)) {
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode,
    header: null,
    headerVisible: false,
  };
};


const MyStack = createStackNavigator({
  screen1: { screen: screen1, navigationOptions: { header: null, headerMode: 'none' } },
  screen2: { screen: screen2, navigationOptions: { header: null, headerMode: 'none'} },
      screen3: { screen: screen3, navigationOptions: { header: null, headerMode: 'none'} },

.
.
});

const MyAppStack = createAppContainer(createDrawerNavigator({
  MyStack: {
    screen: MyStack,
  },
  login: {
    screen: login,
  },
.
.
.
));
```

But, Header is still showing for all the screens.

Even we have tried for individual screen navigation header hiding, But, still not hiding.

```
class login extends Component<Props> {

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you hide the header at the time of creation? eg: const DrawerStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ClassFilter: { screen: ClassFilter },
    EventDetail: { screen: EventDetail }
  },
  { headerMode: "none" }
);

Comment: @JebinBenny not working, Still header showing

Comment: Try setting `headerMode: 'none'`

Comment: headerMode: 'none' this only I have set, But, still not working

Comment: Please update your code and show how have you implemented headerMode none.

Comment: Please check updated code.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper did you try my answer? if it worked please don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Please check my updated query, In MyStack I have to disable swipe/gestures for particular screen

Answer (score 2):

To hide navigation header, add `headerMode` outside of `navigationOptions`. Both should be at same level.

```
export default createStackNavigator({
  ...
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    ...
   }
});
```

**Update 1**

```
const MyAppStack = createAppContainer(createDrawerNavigator({
  MyStack: {
    screen: MyStack,
    navigationOptions: {
          header:false, // or drawerLabel: () => null  

    }
  },
  login: {
    screen: login,
  },
.
.
.
));
```

Comment: For reference: [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/handling-iphonex.html#hidden-custom-navigation-bar-or-tab-bar)

Comment: Oh yes, Please check [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/131#issuecomment-281493120). You may need to change the structure a little

Comment: We can't set just header:null inside MyStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
method?

Comment: In above your code getting error Parsing error: Unexpected token for {
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    ...
   }

Comment: I have added an update to answer, in your drawer navigator, try adding `navigationOption`. Try with `header:false` or `drawerLabel: () => null`

Comment: No, still header is coming

Comment: drawerLabel: () => null this is fixed. But, Other issue came, Now, Drawer not coming for all the screens. I don't want to stop all the screens gestures only selected ones.

Comment: There are different properties provided, you may try `navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
  }`

Comment: Now, Header gone, but drawer opening for all the screens

Comment: I really appreciates your suggestions, Really thanks so much, but, still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192360/discussion-between-dhruv-and-anilkumar-ios-developer).

Answer (score 1):

Hello Anil please try following code

```
MyStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let drawerLockMode = 'unlocked';
  if ((navigation.state.index === 2) || (navigation.state.index === 3)) {
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode,
    header: null,
    headerVisible: false,
  };
};


const MyStack = createStackNavigator({
  screen1: { screen: screen1 },
  screen2: { screen: screen2 },
  .
  }, {
       headerMode: 'none',
       navigationOptions: {
         headerVisible: false,
       });
```

Comment: This part getting syntax errors coming {
       headerMode: 'none',
       navigationOptions: {
         headerVisible: false,
       }); Where are you adding these?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, After somany forums read and some practice, Found the best solution to restrict gestures/swipe for particular screens in React-Native Navigation. Hope this will helps someone in future.

Install following library

```
 import getCurrentRouteName from 'react-navigation-current-route';


    const MyStack = createStackNavigator({
      screen1: { screen: screen1, navigationOptions: { header: null, headerMode: 'none' } },
      screen2: { screen: screen2, navigationOptions: { header: null, headerMode: 'none'} },
      screen3: { screen: screen3, navigationOptions: { header: null, headerMode: 'none'} },

    .
    .
    });

MyStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const currentRoute = getCurrentRouteName(navigation.state);
  let drawerLockMode = 'unlocked';
  if ((currentRoute === 'screen1') || (currentRoute === 'screen2')) {
    drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
  }
  return {
    drawerLockMode
  };
};    

    const MyAppStack = createAppContainer(createDrawerNavigator({
      MyStack: {
        screen: MyStack,
      },
      login: {
        screen: login,
      },
    .
    .
    .
    ));
```